# How to access value in one Ascx control in another Ascx control on the same page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, user-controls

I have a aspx page that has two user controls one with a grid view in it and another with a label in it which is used for displaying user data when he logs in. Now I want use the data from one column in the grid view  to be displayed in the label in second user control. How can I achieve this. The data in the gridview changes for each user based up on his security role.any inputs appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gridview user control raises a custom event when it has the information you need.  The event is handled in the main page and assigned to the UserControl with a label via a public property that has access to the Label Text embedded within the control.

## Default.aspx

Page with both user controls

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="StackOverFlowJunkVB._Default" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControlGridView1.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="WebUserControlGridView1" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControlLabel1.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="WebUserControlLabel1" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <uc1:WebUserControlGridView1 runat="server" id="WebUserControlGridView1" />
    <uc1:WebUserControlLabel1 runat="server" id="WebUserControlLabel1" />
</asp:Content>
```

## Default.aspx.vb

Code behind that assigns text to Label user control via raised event from GridView user control

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page

    Private Sub WebUserControlGridView1_ReallyImportantLabelTextHandler(sender As Object, e As GridViewLabelEvent) _
      Handles WebUserControlGridView1.ReallyImportantLabelTextHandler

        WebUserControlLabel1.ReallyImportLabelText = e.ImportantLabelText

    End Sub
End Class
```

## CodeBehind for the GridView UserControl

```
' Define a custom EventArgs class to pass some really important text
Public Class GridViewLabelEvent
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Property ImportantLabelText As String
End Class

' The user control with a GridView
Public Class WebUserControlGridView1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

  Public Event ReallyImportantLabelTextHandler As EventHandler(Of GridViewLabelEvent)

  Private Sub GridView1_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.DataBound
    Dim gvle As New GridViewLabelEvent
    gvle.ImportantLabelText = "This is really important"
    RaiseEvent ReallyImportantLabelTextHandler(Me, gvle)
  End Sub
End Class
```

## CodeBehind for the Label UserControl

```
Public Class WebUserControlLabel1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    ' Property to assign Label Text
    Public Property ReallyImportLabelText As String
        Get
            Return Label1.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Label1.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```